# Получить ввод из подчинённого псевдотерминала

Tags: linux, bash, консоль, unix

Запустив команду, что выводит приглашение на ввод и запрашивает данные, нужно перенаправить всё это действо в другой pts. Пока получилось перенаправить туда только stdout и stderr (или нет, выводится приглашение ввода данных) `python bin/src/translate.py 2> /dev/pts/2 > /dev/pts/2`

Comment: `< /dev/pts/2`.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin пробовал. Ввод остался с основного окна и перестал передаваться в подчинённое

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin если бы всё было так просто... Могу скрин терминала приложить.

Comment: а код на питоне твой? можно в самом коде перенаправиться?

Comment: @eri да, код мой, но там всё обычно input'ы да print'ы + bs4. И скрипт выбран лишь в качестве примера, надо сделать это с любой прогой/скриптом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вызова `os.setsid()` не хватает для того чтоб передать скрипт в другую консоль...

## Через pty/pts

В шеле есть команда setsid, попробуйте запуститься через неё

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0 & # не знаю как вы подняли pts, сокат для примера
cat < /dev/pts/11 & # второй терминал

setsid python -c "print(input())" < /dev/pts/12 > /dev/pts/12
echo 12223 > /dev/pts/11 # второй терминал
```

И ответ притетел обратно

Терминалы должны быть не занятыми даже bash-ем, поэтому создаю новые сокатом.

## Через fifo решение лучше

```
mkfifo /tmp/py-term
mkfifo /tmp/term-py

python -c "print(input().upper())" > /tmp/py-term < /tmp/term-py
```

на втором терминале почему-то не сработало (может кто подскажет где косяк)

```
cat < /tmp/py-term > /tmp/term-py
```

а вот так пашет

```
cat < /tmp/py-term &
echo asd > /tmp/term-py
```

## Через screen ещё лучше

Не надо думать о перенаправлении - всё работает из коробки.
На первом терминале

```
screen python -c "print(input().upper())"
```

потом кнопками ctrl+a ctrl+d или без кнопок и чтоб было видно завершение

```
screen -dmS pysession sh -c 'python -c "print(input().upper())"; read'
```

на втором терминале

```
screen -rS pysession
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106606/discussion-on-answer-by-eri-----).